# Use custom function in ModelViewSet with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Django 2.0, Python 3.6, Django Rest Framework 3.8

I'm still pretty new to Django Rest Framework, and I'm trying to wrap my head around the logic for using functions in a viewset (and if this is even the correct place to include a function).

Basically, I would like to send out an email when a user posts something to the api in this specific viewset. I tried using the `send_mail` function, but have been unsuccessful. I have the following class based view:

```
class SendInviteView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Message.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.MessageSerializer

    @action(methods=['post'], detail=True)
    def send_the_mail(self, request):
        send_mail(
            'Invitation',
            'Try our app!',
            'exampleemail@gmail.com',
            ['examplerecipient@gmial.com'],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
```

[The Model and Serializer are pretty basic, and I don't think will be required for the context of this problem, basically just an EmailField(). I eventually plan to use the input of that email field to replace `examplerecipient@gmail.com`, but for now I just want to understand how to add functionality to viewsets]

This results in an error when running `python manage.py check`

I have my email client set up through sendgrid and am able to successfully send emails to users who ask to have their passwords reset through `rest-auth`, but I don't understand how sending an email works outside of that context.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include the error you get. Actually your setup is a bit strange. Can you please describe what do you want to achieve. What is meant by "user posts something to the api in this specific viewset"? What data the user will send? When you add `action` it generates additional URL /send_the_email. Is that intended?

Comment: Also with detail=True you will need Message id to perform request. I think you are just a bit overwhelmed by all this concepts,  so try to describe the functionality and I will point you. (will take a look tomorrow)

Comment: Thanks @AlexandrTatarinov . You're right, I think I'm just misunderstanding a lot of the key concepts. From what I understand, my views are where any additional functionality to my api should be placed (filtering the query and writing additional functions). When I say "user posts something" I mean that they will fill in an EmailField in the browsable api, and the address typed in there is the address the message will send to. The data the user will send is the message specified in the function. I used `detail=True` and `action` in an attempt to follow a setup I saw on the DRF documentation.

Comment: do you need to save that message to database? if not, you don't even need the Message model. So as I understood, you want the ability for user to enter email and message, and this message should be sent to that email?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I would like to save the sender and the recipients to the database, but I don't need the message itself saved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the discussion, I would came up with the following.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.db import models
from rest_framework import serializers, viewsets, routers, mixins
from rest_framework.response import Response


class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    recipient = models.EmailField()


class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    message = serializers.CharField(write_only=True) 

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['recipient', 'message']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        message = validated_data.pop('message')
        message_obj = super().create(validated_data)
        send_mail(
            'Invitation',
            message,
            'exampleemail@gmail.com',
            [message_obj.recipient]
        )
        return message_obj

class SendInviteView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(sender=self.request.user)


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('send_invite', SendInviteView, base_name='send_invite')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Let's break things up.

If you want to store sender, you need `ForeignKey` to `User` in your model.

For serializer you need to add `message` field manually because it doesn't exists in your model, but users should submit it. We set it to write-only, because this serializer will be also used to serialize created `Message` back to user for response, and  `Message` don't have `message` field. This serializer will also generate field for `recipient` automatically from `Message` model.

Then we override `create` in this serializer, so whenever new `Message` will be created using it, it will send an email. It calls `super().create(..)` to actually save `Message` to database and then sends an email. We use `.pop()` to remove `message` from `validated_data`, because `Message` doesn't contain such field.

For the view we don't need the whole stuff the `ModelViewSet` provides. It adds ability to Create, Read, Update and Delete (`CRUD`) your `Message`, which is not actually needed. All you need is simple Create which translates to `POST` in term of HTTP request. `GenericViewSet` with `CreateModelMixin` is exactly the thing we want (And actually `ModelViewSet` just have MORE mixins). The data from user will be validated by serializer and than `perform_create` method will be invoked. We are passing `sender=self.request.user` to `serializer.save()` because we need to save `sender` into `Message`, and `sender` field is not actually in the data, it is the user currently logged-in.
`serializer.save()` will run our `MessageSerializer.create()` so we are happy.

Note that this stuff will work only for logged-in users, because we somehow need to populate `sender` field in database, so it will be correct to add

```
class SendInviteView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    ....
```

So only authenticated users can make request.
Hopefully this will clarify things for you. Best regards)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understood correctly, you could mention the function/method in `urls` as below,

```
url(r'some/end/point/', views.SendInviteView.as_view({"post": "send_the_mail"})
```

Hence, your view be like,

```
class SendInviteView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Message.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.MessageSerializer

    def send_the_mail(self, request):
        recipient = request.data['recipient']  # json array
        send_mail(
            'Invitation',
            'Try our app!',
            'exampleemail@gmail.com',
            recipient,
            fail_silently=False,
        )
        return Response("mail sent successfully")
```

Since `recipient` expects an array, so the `POST payload` will be like,

```
{
    "recipient": ["mail1@dom.com", "mail2@dom.com", "mail3@dom.com"]
}
```